# Can i insert external js file in jsp using out.write method

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, jsp

Is it correct in jsp if i insert js file using out.write method

e.g.

```
  // generate graph

        out.write("<canvas id='canvas' height='450' width='600'></canvas>");
        out.write("<script>");
        out.write("var barChartData = {\n");
        out.write("labels : ['Pass','Fail'],\n");
        out.write("datasets : [{\n");
        out.write("fillColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',\n");
        out.write("strokeColor : 'rgba(220,220,220,1)',\n");
        out.write("data : [65,0]},{\n");
        out.write("fillColor : 'rgba(151,187,205,0.5)',\n");
        out.write("data : [0,47]}]}\n");
        out.write("var myLine = new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d')).Bar(barChartData);\n");
        out.write("</script>");


        out.write("</body>\n");

        out.write("</html>\n");

        //Close the output stream
```

i'am getting an error in eclipse saying -

Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
- Chart cannot be resolved
- Syntax error, insert ")" to complete  MethodInvocation
- Syntax error on token "js", ( expected after this  token

Comment: try removing \n first and see it's not a syntax error? haven't worked with Java for a while, but it might be \\n.

Comment: since you write it to `jsp`, it should be `<br/>` instead of `\n` . Is it?

Comment: but all the other places its /n out.write("<HEAD>\n");
      out.write(" <TITLE>Automation Test Results by QA Team</TITLE>\n");
      out.write("<script src='Chart.js'></script>/n");
      out.write("</HEAD>\n");
       
      out.write("<body>\n");

Comment: what is the purpose of `\n` here? It will print exactly `<HEAD>\n` and so on in your `jsp`

Comment: i am trying to insert html 5 graph in it

Comment: @AtalShrivastava And it has nothing to do with `\n`. There is nothing wrong in your above code. can you show us more related codes?

Comment: out.write("<script src='/bpm/scripts/FilterRow.js'></script>\n"); This works exactly as i want on my side. it must be something else . share some lines of code.

Comment: is this the correct way to insert embeded js in jsp

Comment: Why would you use our.write() to write javascript on jsp page instead of directly writing in jsp page?
I have seen this kind of approach in writing javascript, only in days when servlet was used to write webpages and jsp was still to be born.
Although \n is used to escape to next line, in this case, it will be written directly to you jsp page, failing your intended purpose. If you want to write to next line you can use System.getProperty("line.separator").